# Trigger.io: Open url with web browser on Android

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, trigger.io

I have created a button "Share on Twitter" which opens up the url to share on twitter in mobile web browser this works fine on iOS but does nothing on Android.

Is there something I am missing or don't know about?

```
    var send = 'http://twitter.com/share';
    var url =  'http://example.com/';
    var text = "Example Text";
    var openURL = send + "?url=" + url + "&text=" + text;
    window.open(openURL, '_blank'); // opens url
```

Nothing happens on Android but works fine on iOS.

Comment: Hopefully relevant: [_On android opening new webview windows is disabled_](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rhomobile/F7S-ukrxxIs/GP_VO3vsza4J).  [Possible workaround](http://pastie.org/1676080).

Comment: @c24w thanks, Is there no way to give permission?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, I'm just searching around:
[_By default, requests by the HTML to open new windows are ignored. This is true whether they be opened by JavaScript or by the target attribute on a link. You can customize your WebChromeClient to provide your own behaviour for opening multiple windows, and render them in whatever manner you want._](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Trigger apps external pages will by default open in the devices browser, this means you can simply run

```
window.location = 'http://google.com'
```

to open an external url in the browser.

If you want a link the user can click then

```
<a href="http://google.com>Click here</a>
```

Will also open in the devices browser.

If you want the user to browse an external website within your app you can use the tabs module to open a modal browser window the user can close and return to your app. See https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/tabs.html

Comment: @Connerhd that does not work at all, at least `window.open` would work on iOS `window.location` does nothing at all and does the same as `window.open` on Android devices. Its strange because i was sure that that `window.open` use to work. Has there been an update that could have broken this?

Comment: Another note even standard anchor link does not work `<a href="http://google.com" type="_Blank">Link</a>` but if `type="_Self"` it does work but no way back into the app.

Comment: @Eli both window.open and `<a>` links work for me on iOS and Android. I've also updated my answer with a link to details on the tabs module, which might suit your needs better.